# Trouble running a Java.jar file with a Swing GUI on Android phone - Major.Minor Version 52.0 & Main Class Name Missing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, swing, cross-compiling

## Hello!

The goal I have is pretty simple: I want to create an executable .jar file which should be able to bring up a form (made using swing) and write the put-in information into a well structurized plain text file. Due to portability/mobility reasons I will have to run this on an Android phone.

Since Android unfortunately doesn't have native Java support and I am unable to code a real Android application myself, I tried to use a Java emulator. Unfortunately, it appears that a working Java Emulator is hard to find to begin with. *JBED* instantly crashes on my *Medion X701*. [*Netmite*'s Website](http://netmite.com/android), which also seems to offer a .jar to .apk converter, appears to be down. *JBlend* seems to have installed properly, but I do not know how to work with the program now that it presents me nothing but an empty screen with the caption "0 Java ME Application(s)". On the web, I could not find a proper manual. *PhoneME*'s official website was Java.net, which is no longer active. But during my research, I could find an [older Version of *PhoneME*](http://w3epic.com/run-java-apps-j2me-on-android-devices-guide/) which seems to be running well.

As a test, I created a simple jar file that shows a maximized JFrame. Unfortunately, it isn't able to run my simple executable Jar file on my phone. The main reason for that should be the aforementioned error, which implies that the interpreter there is probably Java version 1.7, since PhoneME's last release was in 2015. There are more error messages referring to an "unknown source", which I believe originate from the first error. I tried to recompile my jar file using *Eclipse*, by setting the Compiler compliance level to 1.7 and choosing the jre 1.7 before exporting my project. Unfortunately, this didn't change the error messages I got on PhoneME!

As my last attempt, I created a Startup.class file which does the very same thing as my jar file.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Startup {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame fishForm = new JFrame("Questionnaire");
        fishForm.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        fishForm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I compiled it using the command prompt in order to make sure that it is indeed using java 1.7 as the target. This .class file, which ran fine on my computer, leads me into a different error: *"Main class name missing."*, followed by multiple lines of usage explaination. The command line PhoneME presents doesn't seem to allow me to post command operations myself, as pressing Enter on the virtual keyboard does nothing.

### My Questions

- Is it even possible to run a Java application on Android which relies on the GUI libraries of Swing, or am I wasting my time?
- Is there a different, up-to-date Java emulator for Android which I could use? Or is there a working jar2apk converter somewhere out there?
- If not, then there's probably a reason why Java emulators ceased to exist. Is there a much simpler solution for my initial problem which I am missing?

I'll await your ideas eagerly!